# Адаптив на bootstrap4?

Tags: bootstrap

Есть код на бутстрапе, нужно сделать при адаптиве (<567) такую конструкцию
с
a
b

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
 .x {
  border: 1px solid blue;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <div class="col x">a</div>
    <div class="col x">b</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col x">c</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А вопрос то будет?

Comment: c/b/a /- значит под

Comment: яхятп какие проблемы то.

Comment: это будет order если вы не знаете

Comment: А где вопрос то?